# Getting 401 Client Error in Cloudant after a while

Tags: kubernetes, nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am developing a service in IBM Cloud, and I'm using Cloudant Service.

I'm using the IBM Cloudant Client Library for python to access my database. After pushing my service to a kubernetes cluster, my service is able to be used. It's possible to call the service with no issues for a while. But after one day or something like that, when I call my service, I get 401 Client Error from my cloudant database and I don't know why. The problem is solved if I delete and create the pods/service again in kubernetes.

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Error:

`401 Client Error: Unauthorized unauthorized one of _writer, _creator is required for this request for url: "myurl"`

I'm calling my service in this way:

```
cloudant_client = Cloudant("540...-bluemix",
                       "4276dd...",
                       url="https://540...-bluemix.cloudant.com")
```

Comment: Is the service IAM enabled and uses (expiring) tokens?

Comment: Could you please provide output of `kubectl describe pod <podname>` after you're facing 401 error?

Comment: @felipe are fixed ur issue as am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is facing this..it may also be due to the verison of cloudant installed. The IBM tutorials use an outdated version of cloudant. The latest version allows IAM authentication

```
pip install cloudant
```

Also make sure u add .iam

```
cloudant_client = Cloudant.iam(<credentials>)
```